# How to find out which website the apache2 process was started from?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have several websites running on one Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server, I installed [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/) to record the process information very 10 minutes. So looking at historical information as shown, there are lots of apache2 processes, how do I find out the following:

1. which website started a particular apache2 process? the parent
2. process id PPID of each process

[image]

Comment: If you are using a standard virtual host configuration, any thread can serve requests from any website.

Comment: @datasage where could I get more detailed information/reference about what you have mentioned?

Comment: You can enable server status and see that requests can be served by any thread for any site. As far as I am aware, there is no way to control threads on a virtual host basis.